# Recursion problem in Prolog - getting False instead of True when going out of recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to do a simple program in Prolog that would decide if the predicate is True or False. Basically I solved the problem, but I found one input that does not work. I know why but I have no idea how to solve it.

The predicate is in this form:

```
getPred(L, A, B, Y)

L - is a list containing intv predicates - intv(K,L,V) - < K,L > is interval and V is any value

< A,B > - is an interval

Y - value
```

The task is:

```
If < K,L > is in < A,B > add V to a sum. If it does not belong to < A,B >, ignore it.  
Finally, compare the sum of correct V values with Y. If it is equal - True, otherwise False.
```

Here is the example of correct TRUE predicates:

```
getPred([intv(2,10,15),intv(5,8,23), intv(12,15,8), intv(14,17,13)], 3, 16, 31).
getPred([intv(2,10,15),intv(5,8,23), intv(12,15,8), intv(14,17,13)], 3, 20, 44).
```

My code is:

```
getPred(List, A, B, Y) :-
    S is 0,
    program(List, A, B, Y, S).

program([], _, _, Y, S) :-
    S =:= Y.

program([intv(K,L,V)|P], A, B, Y, S) :-
    isinINTV(K, L, V, A, B, P, Y, S).

isinINTV(K, L, V, A, B, P, Y, S) :-
    K >= A,
    L =< B,
    S2 = S+V,
    program(P,A,B,Y,S2).

isinINTV(K, L, V, A, B, P, Y, S) :-
    program(P,A,B,Y,S).
```

My program worked perfectly unless I tried this predicate 
    getPred([intv(2,10,10),intv(5,8,10)], 1, 20, 10).

The problem is that when Y != S, the recursion is going back and asks the same condition again but later Y == S because going back in recursion means that there is an old value in S.

Thank you for help.
Important thing: I do not want to use any built-in predicates.

Comment: Change `S2 = S+V` to `S2 is S+V`. Don't confuse term unification (`=/2`) with arithmetic evaluation (`is/2`).

Comment: "Important thing: I do not want to use any built-in predicates." `>=/2`, `=</2`, `=:=/2`, and `is/2` **are**  built-in predicates.

Comment: I know. I meant predicates except these that I used already. I mean, I can use "relational operators".
Anyway can you help me with the problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
check(Intervals, Inf, Sup, Value) :-
    check(Intervals, Inf, Sup, 0, Sum),
    Sum =:= Value.

check([], _, _, Sum, Sum).
check([intv(Inf0,Sup0,Value)| Intvs], Inf, Sup, Sum0, Sum) :-
    (   Inf0 >= Inf,
        Sup0 =< Sup ->
        Sum1 is Sum0 + Value,
        check(Intvs, Inf, Sup, Sum1, Sum)
    ;   check(Intvs, Inf, Sup, Sum0, Sum)
    ).
```

Some renaming for easier reading of the code. Sample calls:

```
| ?- check([intv(2,10,15),intv(5,8,23), intv(12,15,8), intv(14,17,13)], 3, 16, 31).
yes

| ?- check([intv(2,10,15),intv(5,8,23), intv(12,15,8), intv(14,17,13)], 3, 20, 44).
yes

| ?- check([intv(2,10,10),intv(5,8,10)], 1, 20, 10).
no
```

Notice that this solution also avoids the spurious choice points in your original code.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please could you explain this line: checka([], _, _, Sum, Sum). to me? I am not really sure how I passed Sum into first predicate so I can compare Sum and Value

Comment: The `check/5` predicate computes the sum, starting from zero, using an accumulator. When we reach the end of the list (or when the input list is empty), the value of the accumulator is the value of the computed sum. Thus, we simply unify the last two arguments.